# why $cordova prepare when use a new phonegap-cordova api(plugin)

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

Im new with phonegap, cordova and android. Im on mac, recently i install all the needs:

Phonegap 3.3.0-0.19.6
Cordova 3.3.1-0.4.1

Got Android SDK and running on eclipse with no problem. Then create a new Android application on eclipse for phonegap successfully, and running on a phone with android.

Then i create another app with cordoba(terminal), put 2 platforms android and ios, i run prepare etc.. and then import the project(android) into eclipse. At this point the app runs ok, so i proceed to install some plugins for testing (Notifications and Device)

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device

When i run the app with eclipse the examples always return

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'alert' of undefined

And its the same with device. So looking over the internet i found that if i run $cordova prepare will work, then i run the command, then run the app on eclipse and it work but always when i install a new plugin for testing i have to run cordova prepare, and the problem is that index.html rewrite with example hello world and i loose my code.

Any help over here, im doing ok?, how to install those plugins and make the test and dont have to run prepare all the time. (Please think on eclipse, i dont what to use terminal all the time)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem and other posts suggestions didn't work for me.

I solved it by switching the steps a bit, despite the official docs and other posts. 
If I add ALL the files AND the core plugins BEFORE I add the platforms, then adding the platforms takes these things with it into the new folder structures **AND only build once from the command line** before I open the project.

If I need to add anything I do it again.  Although I can edit the www files without going through the process again, **I do not expect the root www to perpetuate the platform www's**. I just copy it myself into all the www folders. It shouldn't be this way but I think this is a well documented bug with multiple command line builds, for now and thats my working fix.

Comment: Thx for the answer, i will try ur aproach and ill come back with the result

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to edit html/js/css... in the root www folder of the project, not in the platfotms/xxx folders.

The reason is that if you have multiple platforms, you just need to modify in one place and `cordova prepare` or  `cordova build` or `phonegap build` will propagate your code to all the platforms and update plugins.

If you have only android platform and want to be able to change code directly in eclipse for the platforms/android/assets/www folder, I suggest you create a shell script to

1. copy all the content of projectroot/platforms/android/assets/www to projectroot/www
2. run cordova prepare android

Then, instead of running `cordova prepare android`, you'll just have to run your script after you add new plugins.

### Edit

I think there may be a better way for your problem.

You should be able to use plugman to install your plugins instead of cordova.

First you need to install plugman cli : `npm install -g plugman`

then install a plugin using

```
plugman -d --platform android --project projectname --plugin nameorurlofplugin
```

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html

Answer (score 0):

I had these issues too.

One approach I use now is:

Edit the `index.html` in the platform folders which is `platform/iOS/appname/www` and so. Then add plugins using the normal terminal way using `cordova plugin add` but always run the project using Xcode for iOS and eclipse and not from the terminal because then you will lose your code.

From my experience when you run using `.xcodeproj` or say android project the `www` on the inside is used and if you use `cordova run ios` from terminal the `www` on the outside will overwrite the `www` in the platform folders.

If you get xcode errors saying can't find so and so plugin files just move them to the path the error says xcode expects them to be in.